# Pass c for each value from jsp to Javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, dom-events

I want to pass the multiple values of certain item from jsp to Javascript. Due to my requirement, I need to use Div and within that div, will loop to print out the data.

On the double of certain item row, I want to pass the multiple values from jsp to Javascript.

NOTE: Due to requirement, I can't use select tag, instead need to use Div.

For now, when I use to pass `${food.foodItemId}` in `showDetailData()` method, no data has been passed to Javascript.

```
<div class="scroller" ondblclick="showDetailData(${food.foodItemId},'m','desktop');">
        <c:forEach var="food" varStatus="i" items="${foodItemList}">
            <c:out value="${food.foodName}"/>
            <br><br>
        </c:forEach>
</div>
```

**How can I pass the multiple values  with such format [ `food.foodItemId~food.foodCategoryId~food.foodName~food.foodPortionName`] to Javascript on double click of certain data row like in below code (which was using select tag)?**

Example like below:

```
<option value="<c:out value="${food.foodItemId}"/>~<c:out value="${food.foodCategoryId}"/>~<c:out value="${food.foodName}"/>~<c:out value="${food.foodPortionName}"/>" ><c:out value="${food.foodName}"/></option>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution that matches with my requirement.

I used ul and li tag insides the div which solves my issue and use double click event on ul tag.

```
<div class="scroller">
    <c:forEach var="food" varStatus="i" items="${foodItemList}">
    <c:set var="foodInfo" value="${food.foodItemId}~${food.foodCategoryId}~${food.foodName}~${food.foodPortionName}"/>
    <ul class="scroller_result" ondblclick="showDetailData('${foodInfo}','m','desktop');"">
        <li><c:out value="${food.foodName}"/>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </c:forEach>
</div>
```